# E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists /ci.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages

Tags: apt, package-management

I am relatively new to Ubuntu. Can someone help me to understand the problem?

`sudo apt-get install subversion` returned the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Error!

E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists
/ci.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```